# Is there a "runUntil" function?

Tags: liquibase

We use Liquibase to manage our database schema changes and migrations. However, based on service contracts, we have the need to be able to rever our application to a previous version. That means that we create an intermediate state of the database schema that is compatible with both versions, since some migrations involve removing data that is no longer required or has been migrated to a different format.

This means however, that we have the need to maintain the data as closely as possible in 2 versions of the application. We have tried to do this using change-sets with the `runAlways="true"` flag set.

```
<changeSet id="my-changeset-id" author="me" runAlways="true">
    <preConditions onFail="MARK_RAN">
        <not>
            <changeSetExecuted id="cleanup-change-set" author="me" />
        </not>
    </preConditions>
    <sql>
        SQL MAINTAIN INTERMEDIATE STATE
    </sql>
</changeSet>

<changeSet id="cleanup-change-set" author="me">
    <preConditions onFail="CONTINUE">
        <changeLogPropertyDefined property="cleanup" value="true" />
    </preConditions>
    
    CLEANUP-STATE-HERE
    DROP TABLES
    DROP COLUMNS, etc...
</changeSet>
```

The difficulty is that then liquibase is executed, I see that the change set is evaluated again and again.

```
[INFO] Marking ChangeSet: src/site/resources/deployment/liquibase/my-liquibase-file.xml::my-changeset-id::me ran despite precondition failure due to onFail='MARK_RAN': 
      src/site/resources/deployment/db.changelog-master.xml : <info about my precondition that failed>
```

I would like for some way to say "This change set should be executed repeatedly until a given condition is met. Then the change set is done and should never been looked at again." It doesn't present us with a functional problem. But, it clutters the logs and makes it more difficult to see when there are preconditions that have been incorrectly written that will simply execute and fail forever, which can significantly slow down our liquibase deployment time.

I realize that my example XML here is not the world's most brilliant XML or example, but is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?